# Can off-chain views call on-chain views?

Tags: contract, views, on-chain-views, off-chain-views, metadata

Is it possible to call and process the result of an on-chain view inside an off-chain view that is stored inside contract metadata?

Comment: Yes, you can call `on-chain` views from `off-chain` views. It uses `run_code` RPC endpoint.

Comment: thank you for the info, would you mind replying to the question with this information so that i can mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call on-chain views from off-chain views. `off-chain` views use `run_code` RPC endpoint, which runs some instructions against a given context provided by you, similar to calling an entrypoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can access onchain views through `run_view` RPC on Octez
Not very well documented but you have info in this PR
https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/merge_requests/4810

You can use it via Taquito also https://tezostaquito.io/docs/lambda_view

Comment: i'm looking to call an off-chain view and have that off-chain view call an on-chain view in a totally different contract and process the result

Comment: I'm curious about the use case? Cause onchain views can call other onchain views.
Offchain views are overset by onchain views for most use cases.
Main interest is custom views when you wanna create a view on a older contract

Comment: use case shouldn't matter on a technical forum, but in this instance i have a utility contract that provides a generic but computationally complex service for other contracts to consume via an on-chain view and i would also like to use this computation inside an off-chain view without having to re-implement